# Webgrid data not showing up when published to Azure

Tags: .net, azure, sharepoint, webgrid

I am working on a page that is taking in information from a SharePoint list and putting it into a WebGrid. Currently it works completely fine with localhost and all the data shows up, but as soon as i publish it and navigate to the page the only thing showing on those pages is the headers from the grid itself, and there are no errors when checking the console.

I tried seeing if it was my jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be because the headers are working and other portions of the app that use jQuery are also working. 
The authentication to SharePoint also works because different portions of the same application can reach the same list and update the information.

```
@model List<CalendarEvent>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10,
selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/custom.css" />
}

<main class="vh-main container">
<div id="mainControls" class="container body-content">
    <h2 class="AppointmentHeader">Your Appointments</h2>
    <div id="gridContent">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
              rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
              alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
              mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
              headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
              footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
              selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
              columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("Subject", "Subject"),
                  grid.Column("PatientName", "Patient Name"),
                  grid.Column("StartDate", "Start Date/Time", format: (item) => item.StartDate.DateTimeValue.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt")),
                  grid.Column("EndDate", "End Date/Time", format: (item) => item.EndDate.DateTimeValue.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt")),
                   grid.Column("MeetingUrl","Join Meeting",
                                 format: @<text><a href="@item.MeetingUrl">Join Meeting</a></text>)
                                    ));
        }
        else
        {
            <div id="gridEmptyMessage">
                <b> There are no appointments scheduled for today </b>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check in this kind of scenarios:

1) Open network tab in developer tool in your browser, check if the api for getting the data form Share points is returning data or not.

2) Add the logging and check if Model has data or not.

3) In the dev tools, inspect the div or Web grid and check if your Table rows and columns are visible not hidden.

4)also check  in the console of dev tool that nothing is breaking related to web grid, be it CSS , jquery or any other library.

hope it helps.